# Run application every minute on ios

Tags: ios

I want to run my application every minute in background on iOS. Can I do this ? Is there any example ?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to put your app in the AppStore, this is not possible.

Comment: Serious lack of research here.

Answer (score 3):

Check out https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html
for a look at what you can and cannot do in the background on IOS.

Many tasks which you might want to do in the background can be done through the OS, such as notifications, but when your app is in the background, it should spend the majority of its time in a suspended case unless:
    You need to implement at least one of several specific user services.
    You need to perform a single finite-length task.
    You need to use notifications to alert the user to some relevant piece of information  when your app is not running.
(these were taken from the site I linked)